# What is data-testid in twitter components for Tweeter Unlike Automation Code?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, twitter

I wanted to unlike all liked tweets on Twitter. Since react is developed using tweeter I wanted to do that thing with code. I found the beloved code in Github which we should run on the developer console.

```
setInterval(() => {
  for (const d of document.querySelectorAll('div[data-testid="unlike"]')) {
    d.click()
  }
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)
}, 1000)
```

so this code will run once in every 1000 ms and I will scroll by itself. But I wanted to know the use of data-tested here why he didn't use normal class or id to select tweet like button? What is the difference between data-testid and id? [image: this is the image of the tweet unlike component]

this is the image of the tweet unlike component

Comment: They're just two different attributes, `<div id="hello" data-testid="world">...</div>`. `id`s have to be unique for the page to be valid and can be selected by the specific selector syntax `#hello`. Test IDs can repeat and are selected as shown, using the general attribute selector syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data-testId attribute is supposed to be used as a handle for test code. Its a marker to say "don't change this class as tests rely on it".

If this is not test code above then it's likely sloppy programming practise i.e. a mistake. TestId's should not be used in the actual running code imo.